# API Calls and Lifecycle methods in Angular

Tags: angular, rest, api, ngoninit

I am trying to wrap my head around angular and its lifecycle methods. Below is a cope snippet of my issue. I am trying to grab the logged in user then make an API call to my backend using the user.id. I tried moving the second API call to a lifecycle hook that is further down the chain, but I repeatedly get errors indicating that this.user.id is undefined. When I console log the user object in ngafterviewchecked, it comes through. Any help or general advice on lifecycle hooks would be appreciated. This is running in the app.component.ts file. I had considerable luck with lifecycle methods in React, but angular is throwing me for a loop.

```
users:any;
userNouns:any;

ngOnInit(){
  this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/users/1')
    .subscribe((result)=>{this.user=result})
}

ngAfterViewChecked(){
  console.log(this.user);
  this.http.get(`http://localhost:8000/nouns/${this.user.id}`)
    .subscribe((result)=>{this.userNouns=result})
}
```

Comment: You could move the both calls to `ngAfterViewChecked()` and first call should be converted to promise so after its executed you should do the second call. Or you can do the call in oncompleted event of first call which ensure it is completed and user is assigned

Answer (score 1):

The http request in `ngOnInit` isn't blocking. The component will continue to go through its lifecycle stages while your first http response is pending.

Instead, use an RxJS operator to chain the second request to the first request. You could use either `switchMap` or `concatMap` to chain a single observable to another. You can use `tap` for any side-effects (to do stuff).

```js
users:any;
userNouns:any;

ngOnInit(){
  this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/users/1').pipe(
    tap(result => this.user = result),
    concatMap(user => this.http.get(`http://localhost:8000/nouns/${this.user.id}`)),
    tap(result => this.userNouns = result)
  ).subscribe(() => {
    const contents = this.userNouns.map(noun => noun.content);
    console.log(contents);
  });
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. That worked well. I tried to tack a .map(the higher order function) onto the result because I assume it was an array of objects, but was given an error indicating that it is an object.

I tried entering: this.userNouns=this.userNouns.map((ele)=>ele.content) after the observable chain, but still within the oninit...but it seems like it didnt even evaluate. I am trying to parse the info before manipulating it with other methods. Any suggestions for the best way to do that?

Comment: You mean a bit like I've done in my amended post? I've altered your version to avoid overwriting `this.userNouns` - that doesn't seem right.